# How do I use a Godox X1T to remotely release the shutter and trigger an AD200?

Tags: off-camera-flash, remote, shutter-release, godox

Been trying to find a definitive answer but couldn't and hope someone can help me out.

I need to use the AD200 off-camera and release the shutter away from the camera.

Do I need two X1T transmitters to accomplish this?  One X1T on hotshoe of camera and another X1T in hand away from the camera to release the shutter and pop the AD200?

Will this setup work?

Answer (score 3):

No, this setup won't work. You're close, but not quite right. The X1T is not a receiver (hence, the "T" suffix) or transceiver — it is a transmitter only. So one X1T cannot trigger another X1T.

You still need all the pieces you mentioned, but you also need an X1R to trigger the camera shutter. With wireless remote shutter *and* flash, you have two events:

1. The first event is the wireless signal to trigger the shutter. This is accomplish with an X1T + X1R pair (transmitter + receiver). The X1T is in hand, the X1R is cabled to the camera's shutter release port. Do not put the X1R into the camera's hotshoe.
2. The second event is the camera signaling the hotshoe flash to fire. This triggers the **second** X1T to pop the AD200 (i.e., the 2nd receiver).

Make sure the X1T+X1R pair are using a different channel than the X1T+AD200 pair.

(See also: [Godox - operate camera and speedlight remotely](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4256385#forum-post-60787684) discussion at dpreview.com)

It does seem sort of silly to have two X1's attached to the camera (one attached only by shutter release cable, the other mounted in the hotshoe), but it's really not different than using a X1T+AD200 in conjunction with a different brand dedicated wireless shutter release (such as the Vello Shutterboss, or Phottix Aion, etc.). In fact, personally, I'd probably go that route (if only because dedicted remote shutter releases can also have timers, delay timers, sequences, etc., that you can't do with a simple X1T flash/shutter trigger remote.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and cheapest way to accomplish off-camera light with remote shutter release using Godox is to get [a Flashpoint SPT (single-pin transceiver)](http://flashhavoc.com/flashpoint-r2-spt-single-firing-pin-transceivers-released/). Sadly, this is only a good solution if you live in the USA, because the transceiver is an Adorama Flashpoint exclusive. It's basically a Godox analog to the Yongnuo RF-605.

The SPT transceiver can do double-duty as both the shutter receiver and the flash transmitter with the appropriate delay between the two signal. This way, you can use an X1T/Xpro, etc. in-hand as your remote to control the flash and fire the shutter, while the SPT relays the shutter command to the camera via cable, and then fires the flashes.

Otherwise, as scottbb has pointed out, you need two X1T and one X1R to accomplish this, by using one Tx/Rx pair as shutter release on one channel, and the other X1T and lights on another channel to avoid firing the flashes too early on the shutter signal.